# fetching from a URL shows an error in console even after catching it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, console

Suppose, I have this function with a wrong 'uri' string provided to fetch:

```
function imgChanger(uri) {
    fetch('uri', { mode: 'cors' })//WRONG 'uri' to demonstrate that catch doesn't prevent console's red error
        .then(function (response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (response) {
            img.src = response.data.images.original.url;
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Despite handling the error, I can see a 404 message in the console:

[image]

I have two questions regarding this: why is it being shown despite catching it and how do I handle it?

Comment: the url does not exist

Comment: Running the same code on my browser console, I have `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` in black

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh I got that error too when I hadn't included the `if` statement in my code which is required because fetch() only rejects network errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there's little you can do here. There's [an Issue 124534: Provide a way not to display 404 XHR errors in console](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124534) open in Chromium almost 10 (!) years ago:

> Chromium always displays HTTP 404s as errors in the Javascript
> console.  Apart from forcing line noise onto developers when they may
> not want it (404s can be spotted easily in the 'Network' tab), I think
> this actually goes against the spirit of HTTP.  If you have a
> telephone direcotry lookup, for example, and you GET
> http://myHost/directory/numbers/12345678
>
> ... the server should respond with a 404 if that number was not in the
> directory.  This is even really an 'error' in my opinion - it's just
> information.  Why should Chromium display this as an error in the
> console?

And as you can see, it's still open (and is essentially treated as 'by design'). Here's another telling quote:

> 8 years gone by and I still cannot control how a client responds to a
> request. Our in-house API's have been changed to always respond with
> 200, with a custom status field to correctly filter what is an actual
> error and what is just simply not there.
>
> It's painfully moronic that we have to move away from REST to actually
> use a semantic status.

But rejoice! there seems to be a discussion open in 2021, so hopefully we'll get things moving in the end. Now, unfortunately, it's not that easy:

> There seems to be general agreement that it would be preferable to
> remove these error messages from the console. But it is also very
> likely that currently **a lot of DevTools users depend on these error
> messages in their workflow**. We have not yet found a way to reconcile
> these 2 sides.

And now the obligatory [xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/1172/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just two followups: 1) Are console errors not a problem if they have been caught successfully? 2) How would you recognize if the error displayed in the console has been handled or not?

Comment: It shouldn't matter much: console should essentially be seen just as a logging mechanism. Log might fail - or do weird things - on its own, but that doesn't affect your application, which should care about handling promise rejections on its own.